# Most probable value of $x$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was asked :

> We performed $n$ different trials in which an event $A$ can occur with probability $p$. Let $X$ be the number of occurrences of $A$. Determine the most probable value of $X$.

My try -

$P_X(x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$

By common sense, we know that the middle term $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$ much be the one with largest $nC_x$. Apart from that, I am unable to proceed further to prove that a particular $x$ is most probable.

Or am I reading the question wrong? Are they asking the Expectation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about Stirling's formula?

Comment: It depends on $p$. E.g. if $p=1$ then $n$ is the most probable. No, they are not asking for expectation.

Comment: @drhab So, it does depend on $p$. Can you elaborate on how it changes for $p=0$ to $1$ ? Thank you.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I do. How can I use that here? Do you intend to differentiate over x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that: $$\frac{P_X(x+1)}{P_X(x)}=\frac{p(n-x)}{(1-p)(x+1)}$$

Thus:

- $P_X(x+1)>P_X(x)$ when $\frac{p(n-x)}{(1-p)(x+1)}>1$ or simplified:  $x<pn-\left(1-p\right)$
- $P_X(x+1)=P_X(x)$ when $x=pn-\left(1-p\right)$
- $P_X(x+1)<P_X(x)$ when $x>pn-\left(1-p\right)$

$P_X$ increases up to a point and then decreases. Find the last $\tilde{x}$ for which $\tilde{x}\leq pn-\left(1-p\right)$. The next value must be (weakly) larger, but none can be larger than that. $\tilde{x}+1$ is a mode. But note there are two modes when this holds with equality.

**Some pictures:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also note that the graph of $P_X$ is concave, so once you find $x$ with $P_X(x+1)<P_X(x)$, you've found the max.

Comment: @CommonerG That's a really good way to solve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ian Technically, $P_X$ is quasi-concave, but that is sufficient.

Comment: @CommonerG I mean sure, it's a discrete graph, but still. The worst thing that can happen is that you can have $P_X(x)=P_X(x+1)$.

Comment: I think you have a fencepost error. For instance when $n=8,p=1/2$, $np-(1-p)=4-1/2=3.5$. Then $\tilde{x}=4$, which is the mode, and $3$ is not the mode.

Comment: You're right. I've written it wrong, it should go the other way'round. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score -3):

Because we have a discrete number of events with two possible outcomes, this is just a binomial distribution. The mean number of successes $X$, given $n$ trials with probability of success $p$, is $X = np$. (This can be proved by summing over all possible numbers of successes from $0$ to $n$; see the proof on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mean).)

Comment: I think you are confusing "most probable" with "expected".

Comment: @Justpassingby I think so too.

Comment: @Justpassingby What's the difference in this case? Is it just that if $n$ is odd, we have two different possible values for $X$?

Comment: $X$ is always an integer, but in general $np$ is not. So they can't be equal.

Comment: @DylanSp We are looking for the value(s) of $x$ where $P_X(x)$ is maximal. That is not necessarily the integer closest to the expected value of $X.$

Comment: @TonyK Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.